# tensorflow softmax always return 1

Tags: tensorflow, softmax

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[0,0,1], [1,1,1], [1000,200,300], [-3000,-0.2,0]])

k = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,3])
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,1]))

model = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(k,w)+b)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(model, {k:a}))
```

out:

```
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

I don't understand why I always receive 1, no matter of input, no matter if I include bias B... Any ideas? Would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `model = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(k,w)+b)`
to `model = tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(tf.matmul(k,w)+b, [-1]))`

The output of `tf.matmul(k,w)+b` is a 2D array. In your case, [4,1].
But the `reduce_sum` in `tf.nn.softmax()` is by default applied to the last axis. You always got 1 b/c you only have 1 elements in each line. `tf.reshape` change the size of `tf.matmul(k,w)+b` to [4].

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me you need to provide the `dim` argument to `softmax` as `0` so it calculates the ***column softmax*** instead of ***row softmax*** (by default dim=-1); Since for each row you have only one element *(w.shape[1] == 1)*, whatever the value is, `softmax` gives `1`:

```
model = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(k,w) + b, dim=0)
```

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
​
​
a = np.array([[0,0,1], [1,1,1], [1000,200,300], [-3000,-0.2,0]])
​
k = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,3])
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,1]))

model = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(k,w) + b, dim=0)   
​   ​
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(model, {k:a}))

[[  0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00]
 [  1.61103498e-12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your code into two steps:

```
mul_tensor = tf.matmul(k,w)+b
model = tf.nn.softmax(mul_tensor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    #print(sess.run(model, {k:a}))
    print(sess.run(mul_tensor, {k:a}))
```

You will get answer of

```
array([[   0.69425076],
       [   1.7690506 ],
       [  41.94503021],
       [ 309.35256958]], dtype=float32)
```

So you are applying softmax on 1 * 1 entry which will return you 1 always.